# If I use "on" with jQuery do I need to include this function inside a document ready?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$("#menu, #home").on('click', 'a', function() {
    //  javascript code
 });
```

But it's not inside a document ready? Will it still work okay even if the #menu or #home are not yet part of the DOM?

Comment: don't think so... Why would you want that?

Comment: Well how does it know to work if it cannot attach to the elements because they don't yet exist ?

Comment: I am not sure how to try this because I think it depends on timing. Yes it seems to work but that might be because the script takes time to load and because the elements are already there. I want to be sure if it works under all conditions.

Comment: so you have tried it and it works?

Comment: make an alert inside and check it out

Comment: Yes it works. But does it work because the script is delayed and slow. I am not trying to be lazy by asking others without testing. I just don't understand if it's an okay thing to do to code click events to things if they are not yet part of the DOM by using "on". Maybe it works because by the time my script is there the DOM is loaded. I just don't have a way to test that.

Comment: Which version of jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this will work (if you'll adjust a selector) without need to wait for a DOM ready as long as you use jQuery 1.7+ since this form of event binding is a something that was achieved using `live` or `delegate` in previous jQuery versions:

See [documentation for `live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu a, #home a', function() {
  //  javascript code
});
```

Comment: How does it attach to the elements if they are not there yet?

Comment: While this is true, the code provided here does not do the same thing as the OP posted, as you will delegate all events to the document instead of the specified containers.

Comment: @David, yep, you are correct. Code here is (possibly) what OP want to achieve and the documentation linked is something OP want to read. Probably wording is screwed and the answer indeed should start with "No, it won't work, but..." :)

Answer (score 3):

No it won’t work (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/BkxqY/). The element you attach the handler to need to exist. However you can always delegate to an element higher up in the DOM that does exists when the script is executed. F.ex, this won’t work:

```
<script>
    $('#menu').on('click', function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
</script>
<a id="menu" href="#">click</a>​
```

But this will:

```
<div id="menu">
    <script>
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
    </script>
    <a href="#">click</a>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You can always delegate to the `document` regardless of when you attach the handler, as the `document` should always be available, f.ex:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '#menu a', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
</script>
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#">click</a>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to what the other answers state it will not work unless the selected elements are already present in the dom. It will work if they don't have any anchor elements yet and that those are added prior to the click event

you can try this out easily. In chrome open the dev console and type

```
$(".hopscoth").on("click","div",function(){alert("I've been clicked");});
$("body").prepend("<div class='hopscoth'><div> text </div></div>");
```

and the click the newly inserted `text` at the top of the page

then execute the first line again and click `text`one more time. The alert is fired the second time but not the first

in other words the first selector has to be present. In your case that is the `#menu` and `#home` elements have to be present. The secondary selector doesn't have to match anything before the event is fired. So you could add the anchor element(s) later than you attach the event handler using .on

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not needed. You need it if you want the script executed at the end of page loading.

You can see an example of this function, that's not executed on `$(document).ready(function()`, [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

In your script, there are `#menu, #home`. The elements with those IDs need to exist if you want the script executes like you want.

Comment: So this will work even if those elements are not yet part of the DOM?

Comment: I think this won't work until you add the elements to the DOM and are part of the DOM. How the script can work without any reference to the element? :-) You are using #menu and #home, and you're pointing to specifical elements with that ID. If you want to test the script, you need to add that elements to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Will work if code is placed after the elements `#menu` and `#home` but not before without a ready event block

DEmo with 2 click handlers, one before element placed in DOM, one after
http://jsfiddle.net/hhkKE/